Can anyone help me in converting older spring security authorization code to latest spring security 6 code
Current older sprint secutity code:
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/**")
            .authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().antMatcher("/tdgp/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
            .hasAnyRole("Admin", "BasicUser").and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").and().rememberMe()
            .key("rememebrKey").rememberMeParameter("spring_security_remember_me")
            .rememberMeCookieName("rememberme").useSecureCookie(false);


  @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .securityMatcher("/tdgp/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(c -> c
                        .requestMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("Admin", "BasicUser")
                )
                .formLogin(c -> c.loginPage("/login"))
                .rememberMe(c -> c.key("rememebrKey").rememberMeParameter("spring_security_remember_me").rememberMeCookieName("rememberme").useSecureCookie(false))
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

